# Can't get data from combineLatest - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, resolver

I'm trying to get files included in logs of a post. What am I doing wrong here? Data is not coming later in chain when I'm trying to `pipe` result of `combineLatest`. The whole code is used in data resolver service.

```
return this.API.getPost(route.params.id).pipe(
  switchMap((response: any) => {
    if (response["logs"]) {
      response["logs"].map(logs => {
        if (logs["files"]) {
          return combineLatest(
            ...logs["files"].map(file=>
              this.API.getFile(file.id)
            )
          ).pipe(
            // Not getting any files from this.API.getFile(file.id)
            map(files =>
              files.map(file => ({
                url: this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
                  window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
                )
              }))
            )
          ),
            map(files => {
              logs["files"] = files;
              return response;
            });
        }
      });
    }
    return of(response);
  })
)
```

Comment: can you try adding a `take(1)` in your `pipe`?

Comment: which version of RxJs are you using

Comment: @Wilt I'm using RxJs 6

Comment: Before `if (response["logs"])`, `console.log(response)`, to make sure `logs` is an array and it has `files` which is an array. Then do a `console.log('before combineLatest`)` on top of the `combineLatest` to ensure you reach there. An operator that can help you in debugging inside of the `.pipe` is the `tap` operator. You can use it to debug your streams by putting `debugger;` inside of it or `log statements.

Comment: Your brackets don't seem to balance. Is this a verbatim copy of your code?

Comment: @AliF50 Both logs and files are arrays. I will try your advice with debugger.

Comment: @KurtHamilton You are right, updated my code.

Comment: @ShabbyAbby I don't get how this is meant to run. Inside your `switchMap` you're only ever returning `of(post)`. The whole if block is just mapping to an array of `combineLatest` - you're not returning the `combineLatest` array out of the if block. This is why I asked if the code is a verbatim copy. You could remove the whole if block and the functionality remains the same.

Comment: @KurtHamilton The only reason for if check is because of not all posts have logs and logs are not always having a file. If I skip them I will get error about undefined value.

Comment: @ShabbyAbby Can you replicate this with mock http calls in stackblitz?

Comment: @ShabbyAbby And by mock calls, I just mean stubs that return `of(mockData)`

Comment: I know why the if check itself is there, but what you're doing inside the if block is creating an unused array of observables - you're not returning the observable to the `switchMap`. So the `switchMap` will *always* run `of(response)`

Comment: @ShabbyAbby This stackblitz demonstrates what I'm talking about: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahyspg `if(value === 1)` passes, but the map doesn't actually return the `combineLatest` array to the `switchMap`. I have to `forkJoin` the `combineLatest` array and return it to `switchMap` to execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your problem

You're not returning the `combineLatest` observable to your `switchMap`.

Inside your `if` block in `switchMap`, you are just creating an unused map of observables.

In a very simplified way, you are currently doing this:

```js
switchMap(response =>
  if (response["logs"]) {
    response["logs"].map(logs => of(logs));
  }

  return of(response);
}
```

I've simplified your combine latest into an `of` to demonstrate the problem. When the `if` condition passes, the block will create a new array, which is then immediately ignored. This means that regardless of your if condition, `switchMap` will always invoke `of(response)`. Your `combineLatest` array will *never* run.

#### A solution

You need to return some kind of observable from your `if` block. If you think about the data type you are creating, it is an array of observables. So for that you will need a `forkJoin` to run an array of observables and return a single observable that `switchMap` can switch to.

```js
return this.API.getPost(this.route.params.id).pipe(
  switchMap((response: any) => {
    if (response["logs"]) {
      return forkJoin(response["logs"].map(logs => {
        if (logs["files"]) {
          return combineLatest(
            ...logs["files"].map(file=>
              this.API.getFile(file.id)
            )
          ).pipe(
            map(files =>
              files.map(file => ({
                url: this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
                  window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
                )
              }))
            )
          ),
            // Not sure what this is???
            map(files => {
              logs["files"] = files;
              return response;
            });
        }
      }));
    }
    return of(response);
  })
)
```

Additionally, I'm not sure what the purpose of the `map` is that I've commented - it's currently serving no purpose, and it may even cause compilation issues.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5jgk9z

This demo is a simplistic abstraction of your problem. The "not working" version creates a map of observables that it doesn't return. The "working" version switches to a `forkJoin` and returns that. In both cases, the condition guarding the `if` block is true.

#### Optimising the observable creation

I think the creation of the inner observables can be simplified and made safer.

It seems a little redundant to wrap an array of `combineLatest` in a `forkJoin`, when you can just use `forkJoin` directly.

And to make it clearer, I would separate the array mapping from the observable creation. This would also help you avoid bugs where you end up with an empty array going into `combineLatest` or `forkJoin`.

```js
// inside the "if" block

// flatten files
const files = response["logs"]
  .filter(log => !!log.files)
  .map(log => log.files)
  .flat();

if (files.length > 0) {
  const observables = files.map(file => this.API.getFile(file.id));
  return forkJoin(observables).pipe(
    map(files => {
      files.map(file => ({
        url: this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
          window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
        )
      }))
    })
  );
}
```

This uses the `.flat()` array function which takes a multi-dimensional array like:

```
[
 [1,2,3],
 [4,5,6]
]
```

and flattens it out to this:

```
[ 1,2,3,4,5,6 ]
```

If you need IE support and don't have a polyfill, you can use an alternative from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat.

I would also recommend creating some interfaces and using strong typing. You soon start to get lost if you're relying solely on good variable naming (not that we ever give variables bad names, of course...)

Comment: Thank you for a really good explanation of the issue. You are right, combineLatest never run.

Comment: I've added an alternative example, which I think should be better. Firstly, get the files, and then if you have files, create the observable array and return a `forkJoin`. It's simpler, less error-prone, and easier to understand in my opinion.

Comment: I have used the last map to connect files back to the correct log. Your second solution is working much smoother.

Comment: Your optimized solution worked perfectly. Anyway I found that there is no point to load files in resolver since it can be a lot of files under one post and it will force user to download all of files without always needing them.

Comment: What this "!!log.files" means??

Comment: @Cabuxa.Mapache In javascript, the !! (bang bang) operator evaluates a truthy value as a boolean. It is the opposite of the ! operator.
So for `var a = '';`, `!a` evaluates to `true`, `!!a` evaluates to `false`. It's not strictly necessary in the answer. It is necessary if doing strict equality checks though.

Answer (score 0):

> Be aware that `combineLatest` **will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value**. This is the same behavior as `withLatestFrom` and can be a gotcha as there will be no output and no error but one (or more) of your inner observables is likely not functioning as intended, or a subscription is late.

Maybe one of your API calls to:

```
this.API.getFile(file.id)
```

returns an error or never completes?

This comes straight [from the documentation here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest)

---

### UPDATE:

After mentioning [in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60550175/cant-get-data-from-combinelatest-angular/60550337#comment107121505_60550175) that you use RxJs 6, you need to know that `combineLatest` expects an array as an argument.

So you should consider changing to:

```
return combineLatest(
  logs["files"].map(
    file => this.API.getFile(file.id);
  ),
);
```

Comment: I get the values of combineLatest if I try to subscribe to it instead to pipe it.

Comment: @ShabbyAbby If that is the case there doesn't seem to be any problem; do you ever subscribe to your piped result?

Comment: It should happen when I subscribe to `this.route.data` in component.

Comment: @ShabbyAbby I see the other answer solved your problem... Nice!